# live-reload is creating these annoying warnings

Tags: angularjs, express, npm

I get all these warnings when using live-reload.
I don't even know what all those scripts are?
What is causing those warnings?

[image]

```
'//@ sourceURL' and '//@ sourceMappingURL' are deprecated, please use '//# sourceURL=' and '//# sourceMappingURL=' instead.
__browserify_process:1 '//@ sourceURL' and '//@ sourceMappingURL' are deprecated, please use '//# sourceURL=' and '//# sourceMappingURL=' instead.
package.json:1 '//@ sourceURL' and '//@ sourceMappingURL' are deprecated, please use '//# sourceURL=' and '//# sourceMappingURL=' instead.
browser.js:1 '//@ sourceURL' and '//@ sourceMappingURL' are deprecated, please use '//# sourceURL=' and '//# sourceMappingURL=' instead.
package.json:1 '//@ sourceURL' and '//@ sourceMappingURL' are deprecated, please use '//# sourceURL=' and '//# sourceMappingURL=' instead.
shoe.js:1 '//@ sourceURL' and '//@ sourceMappingURL' are deprecated, please use '//# sourceURL=' and '//# sourceMappingURL=' instead.
package.json:1 '//@ sourceURL' and '//@ sourceMappingURL' are deprecated, please use '//# sourceURL=' and '//# sourceMappingURL=' instead.
browser.js:1 '//@ sourceURL' and '//@ sourceMappingURL' are deprecated, please use '//# sourceURL=' and '//# sourceMappingURL=' instead.
stream:1 '//@ sourceURL' and '//@ sourceMappingURL' are deprecated, please use '//# sourceURL=' and '//# sourceMappingURL=' instead.
events:1 '//@ sourceURL' and '//@ sourceMappingURL' are deprecated, please use '//# sourceURL=' and '//# sourceMappingURL=' instead.
util:1 '//@ sourceURL' and '//@ sourceMappingURL' are deprecated, please use '//# sourceURL=' and '//# sourceMappingURL=' instead.
package.json:1 '//@ sourceURL' and '//@ sourceMappingURL' are deprecated, please use '//# sourceURL=' and '//# sourceMappingURL=' instead.
sockjs.js:1 '//@ sourceURL' and '//@ sourceMappingURL' are deprecated, please use '//# sourceURL=' and '//# sourceMappingURL=' instead.
url:1 '//@ sourceURL' and '//@ sourceMappingURL' are deprecated, please use '//# sourceURL=' and '//# sourceMappingURL=' instead.
querystring:1 '//@ sourceURL' and '//@ sourceMappingURL' are deprecated, please use '//# sourceURL=' and '//# sourceMappingURL=' instead.
inject.js:1 '//@ sourceURL' and '//@ sourceMappingURL' are deprecated, please use '//# sourceURL=' and '//# sourceMappingURL=' instead.
package.json:1 '//@ sourceURL' and '//@ sourceMappingURL' are deprecated, please use '//# sourceURL=' and '//# sourceMappingURL=' instead.
index.js:1 '//@ sourceURL' and '//@ sourceMappingURL' are deprecated, please use '//# sourceURL=' and '//# sourceMappingURL=' instead.
backoff.js:1 '//@ sourceURL' and '//@ sourceMappingURL' are deprecated, please use '//# sourceURL=' and '//# sourceMappingURL=' instead.
fibonacci.js:1 '//@ sourceURL' and '//@ sourceMappingURL' are deprecated, please use '//# sourceURL=' and '//# sourceMappingURL=' instead.
strategy.js:1 '//@ sourceURL' and '//@ sourceMappingURL' are deprecated, please use '//# sourceURL=' and '//# sourceMappingURL=' instead.
exponential.js:1 '//@ sourceURL' and '//@ sourceMappingURL' are deprecated, please use '//# sourceURL=' and '//# sourceMappingURL=' instead.
widget.js:1 '//@ sourceURL' and '//@ sourceMappingURL' are deprecated, please use '//# sourceURL=' and '//# sourceMappingURL=' instead.
package.json:1 '//@ sourceURL' and '//@ sourceMappingURL' are deprecated, please use '//# sourceURL=' and '//# sourceMappingURL=' instead.
index.js:1 '//@ sourceURL' and '//@ sourceMappingURL' are deprecated, please use '//# sourceURL=' and '//# sourceMappingURL=' instead.
other.js:1 '//@ sourceURL' and '//@ sourceMappingURL' are deprecated, please use '//# sourceURL=' and '//# sourceMappingURL=' instead.
reload.js:1 '//@ sourceURL' and '//@ sourceMappingURL' are deprecated, please use '//# sourceURL=' and '//# sourceMappingURL=' instead.
```

Comment: Please post the relevant details needed to reproduce your issue in the question.  Please see [MCVE].

Answer (score 0):

`sourceURL` is a information in a `*.map` file in order to make debugging easier when using preprocessors. They changed the syntax a while ago, as somewhere in your code the old syntax is used, that's the reason for the warning. See also: 
https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2013/06/sourceMappingURL-and-sourceURL-syntax-changed?hl=en

old:

```
//@ sourceURL
//@ sourceMappingURL
```

new:

```
//# sourceURL
//# sourceMappingURL
```

Are you using `Grunt/Gulp` or/with a preprocessor e.g. like `SCSS` or `TypeScript`? Check your generated `*.map` files for the `CSS` and `JS` files which you include in your page. If there's somewhere the old syntax. If you find it somewhere you can try to update your Preprocessor. You can also try to update Browsersync and other Node modules. Next you can try to remove all your `node_modules` and reinstall them while making sure no preprocessor automatically creates `*.map` files in the `node_modules` directory.

In general it's nothing to worry about, but at some point you will probably not be able to debug that good anymore directly in the browser, if you don't change it.

Here more information about the use of `sourceURL`:
https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/debug/readability/source-maps?hl=en#sourceurl-and-displayname